# Keep UITextField from resigning first responder status

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, first-responder, resignfirstresponder, becomefirstresponder

In my UITableView I have only a single cell, with a UITextField in it. The setup is identical to the change phone name table view on the iPhone with iOS 5. The problem is, whenever the user drags the cell up so that it moves out of view, and then it falls back down again, the text field resigns its first responder status because the cell is being reloaded. How can I keep this from happening, given that the table view only has one cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final solution ended up being disabling scrolling for the table view- this way the cell is never recycled and the keyboard is never dismissed.